# move pdf and prc files to another location Python

Tags: python, pdf

hi I have a folder with a mix of .pdf .mobi .txt .docx .prc and sub-folders, so I used the following to move everything except sub-folders:

```
def checkbook(file):
    if file.lower().endswith ('mobi' or 'pdf' or 'azw3' or 'txt' or 'epub' or 'docx' or 'doc' or 'prc' or 'azw'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

files = os.listdir(from_path)
for file in files:
    if checkbook(file) == True:
       shutil.move(src, dst)
```

it works perfectly well with mobi files but whenever it comes to pdf or prc files, the  checkbook(file) returns a False value.

Comment: also it seems to return False for azw3 or azw files as well

Comment: This only works for "mobi" because of the way boolean expressions are evaluated in python. When an _and_ or _or_ expression is satisfied, the value of the expression is the last evaluated value. In `'mobi' or 'pdf ...` "mobi" is a non-empty string so is "truthy". The _or_ is satisfied and no more evaluation of the rest of the expression is even attempted and the value of that entire expression is always simply "mobi".

Comment: so the rest of files will be tested if they are mobi files? And if I put `'pdf' or 'mobi'...` then it will only work for pdf files?

Comment: Yes, its because that entire expression evaluates to "mobi". Try `print('mobi' or 'pdf' or 'azw3' or 'txt' or 'epub' or 'docx' or 'doc' or 'prc' or 'azw')` and you'll see. You can do other experiments like `print(False or 100)` or `print(1 and 2)` to see how it works. Note that the linked answer shows you how to use a tuple to get what you want. If you pass the tuple to `endswith` it will check if any match.